# Windows phone marketplace: how can I stop an app submission?

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I've seen that when I submit an app to the Marketplace I cannot stop submission process if I find a bug in my app and have to wait the submission for sending a patch.

Is there a way to stop the submission if I find an error to avoid to send a buggy version of my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to stop the submission if I find an error to avoid to send a buggy version of my app?

No. You'll have to wait for it to be (dis)approved.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't stop the submission, what you can do, is change it to publish manually, so that the buggy version won't actually go live if it does pass certification.

Answer (score 0):

The DevCenter for Windows Phone has now been updated, so it is possible to easily cancel an update.  This was not possible before a few weeks ago.